# How to run a Windows container inside Windows Subsystem for Linux (WSL)?

Tags: docker, dockerhub

I have managed to install docker on Windows, and I can run docker from my Ubuntu bash prompt of the WSL. But when I try to pull or run a Windows image from docker hub, I get the following error:

```
root@DESKTOP-J9B5HJG:~# docker info  -f '{{.OSType}}/{{.Architecture}}'
linux/x86_64
root@DESKTOP-J9B5HJG:~# docker pull mcr.microsoft.com/windows:1809-amd64
Error response from daemon: manifest for mcr.microsoft.com/windows:1809-amd64 not found
root@DESKTOP-J9B5HJG:~#
```

Comment: Your answer is in the documentation: https://docs.docker.com/docker-for-windows/#switch-between-windows-and-linux-containers

Answer (score 4):

`C:\Users\romain.prevost>docker info  -f '{{.OSType}}/{{.Architecture}}'
'linux/x86_64'`

Now, if you are running Docker for Windows, right click the Docker icon in your tray, and select "Switch to windows containers"

`C:\Users\romain.prevost>docker info  -f '{{.OSType}}/{{.Architecture}}'
'windows/x86_64'`

Voilà! Essentially, Docker for Windows includes two different engines : Linux in a VM, and Windows, natively on your windows kernel. But soon, there will be options to run Linux containers natively on the Windows kernel. Exciting times!

Comment: AFAIK only Windows Server can run native containers without Hyper-V, though.

Comment: Windows 10 can, starting from the Pro version.

Comment: The reason: all Windows native images are based on Server editions which are supposed to run on a different kernel.

Comment: Hoooooo, I did not know about Hyper-V isolation on Windows 10 for Windows containers. Thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

To run windows container you need a windows docker engine.
Have a look to this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42158596/can-windows-containers-be-hosted-on-linux

Comment: That's a bit terse as an answer, if this SO Q/A happens to get deleted there's nothing left here. Attributing is necessary of course, but please take some time to write in your own words how this linked answered match this question here.